# can't add library directory to ld

Tags: linux, ld

I have created my own library directory in my home (`/home/mathieu/lib`). I have one lib called `libmath.so` in this directory.
To add this directory to `ld`, I have added the path in te file `/etc/ld.so.conf`. I've reloaded the cache by executing `sudo ldconfig`.
When I execute `sudo ldconfig -p | grep libmath.so` I get `libmath.so (libc6) => /home/mathieu/lib/libmath.so`. So it works.

#### The problem

When I execute `ld -lmath` I get:

```
attempt to open /usr/i486-linux-gnu/lib32/libmath.so failed
attempt to open /usr/i486-linux-gnu/lib32/libmath.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib32/libmath.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib32/libmath.a failed
attempt to open /lib32/libmath.so failed
attempt to open /lib32/libmath.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib32/libmath.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib32/libmath.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmath.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmath.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libmath.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libmath.a failed
attempt to open /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmath.so failed
attempt to open /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmath.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libmath.so failed
attempt to open /lib/libmath.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmath.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmath.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libmath.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libmath.a failed
ld: cannot find -lmath
```

`ld` doesn't even seek in `/home/mathieu/lib` path.

`gcc test.c -o test -lmath`returns

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmath
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do you have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `gcc test.c -o test -lmath -L$HOME/lib`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, that works but I don't want to use this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIBRARY_PATH` to add the directory to be searched by `gcc` for compiling,

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib
```

or, you can add the library to the `-L` command line flag to `gcc` like

```
gcc test.c -o test -lmath -L$HOME/lib
```

The issue is that your modification to `/etc/ld.so.conf` will be used at application start-time to find the correct library (not at compile time).